# Problem in Deploying a sharepoint-hosted application

Tags: sharepoint-online, visual-studio

I am using `visual studio` for creating my application, at first I had created 2 lists, the deployment is good and no issues but when I created more lists, I get this error during the deployment :

```
@"Error 1
    CorrelationId: e156482e-20b4-48e8-8557-1fa4d0084fda
    ErrorDetail: There was a problem with activating the app web definition.
    ErrorType: App
    ErrorTypeName: App Related
    ExceptionMessage: Cannot complete this action.
```

What is the reason of this issue? and how to solve this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your `ProductID` from `AppManifest.xml` file and deploy again.

```
<App xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2012/app/manifest"
     Name="PeopleApp"
     ProductID="{Put a new id here}"
     Version="1.0.0.0"
     SharePointMinVersion="15.0.0.0"
>
```

`ProductID` should be a guid. In VS, click on TOOLS --> Create GUID --> New GUID --> Copy & paste.

Also check the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20510177/1294606)

> It is because SharePoint is trying to activate your app as a standard
>   SharePoint feature, when its really an App.
>
> In the features folder of the SharePoint project, there will be a
>   Feature named Feature1.
>
> Open Feature1 and ensure it's contained in the "Items in the solution"
>   list and not in the "Items in the feature" list.
>
> After that you should be able to deploy.

Comment: Still having the same error.! :(

Comment: Update the app version also

Comment: I still don't have any luck sir.!!

Comment: Did you check my last update?

Comment: the issue solved by transferring all the items from solution into the feature.. in the feature1 !!! cheers..

Comment: I faced this issue some days ago and solved by changing ProductID. Anyway good to know that your problem is solved. cheers

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue today and after trying all of the solutions on here and elsewhere, I finally managed to solve it.

There was a issue with the last three fields that I have added in my list. I deleted them and recreated them and voila!

Issue gone.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something is probably doubled. Check the ids, paths, and names of everything that you added sinced the last successful deploy.  Lists, Fields, Content Types, Views, etc.